# How to Unit Test Custom methods in Spring JPA Repository with H2 Database

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to to write unit test for the custom method i added to the CrudRepository interface. Problem am facing is all Crud defualt methods are executing and my custom method always returning empty dataset. For example findOne(id) , findAll are working fine without any issue. Struggling at the moment to find an answer.

**Entity class for DB Table account**

```
@Entity(name = "account")
public class Account implements Serializable {

    /**
    * UUID
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3918263534182744304L;
    /**
    * Primary Key account Id {@link Long}
    */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "accountId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long accountId;
    /**
    * Actual accountID received from Sales-force
    */
    @Size(max = 18)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    /**
    * Name of the account
    */
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    /**
    * Type of the account
    */
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    //other fields and getter and setters
}
```

**Repository Interface**

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long>{
    Collection<Account> findByType(final String type);
}
```

**Spring Unit Test class**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Transactional
public class AccountRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    private Long accountId_1 = 1L;
    private Long accountId_2 = 2L;

    @Before
    public  void init() {

         //account 1
         Account account = setAccount("Credit");
         entityManager.persist(account);
         entityManager.flush();
         logger.info("Account Id Inserted: " + account.getAccountId() + " | " + account.toString());
         accountId_1 = account.getAccountId();

         //account 2
         account = setAccount("Debit");
         entityManager.persist(account);
         entityManager.flush();
         logger.info("Account Id Inserted: " + account.getAccountId() + " | " + account.toString());
         accountId_2 = account.getAccountId();
    }

    @Test
    public void accountTypeTest() {
        Account retrieved = accountRepository.findOne(accountId_2);
        //correctly returning the object with accountId == accountId_2

        Collection<Account> accountRetrived = accountRepository.findByType(retrieved.getType());
        // Always returning empty result set
        assertTrue(accountRetrieved.size() > 0); 
    }

    /*
    * Method will create the Account dummy object.
    */
    private Account setAccount(final String type) {
        final Account account = new Account();
        account.setiD("ID");
        account.setName("AccountName");
        account.setType(type);
        return account;
    }

}
```

- Problem is when am using a defualt method from Crud its working fine, returing the object correctly. for example if am using findOne(id) or findAll().
- When i tried to call findByType(String type) method from repository in my log i can see the query correctly printing ( enabled log in trace mode and see the value passed also its printing correctly )
- Why am not able to receive the data ?

Comment: Hey @Arundev, I just replicated your code and I noticed that your problem is in the account repository. If you remove "propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW" from Transactional, the test will work. Unfortunately, I can't explain why that configuration makes the custom method fail. I hope someone can say something about it.
Moreover, you don't need the Transaction in your test.

Comment: @Cata OMG.... Hey... its worked.... thank you so much.